# "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" error at boot

Tags: boot, mount

When i boot my computer . It shows a error in boot screen that "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" but it starts normally if i leave it . I want to stop this error from showing up please help . I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Type into your terminal $ sudo gedit

Click the "open file" button

click "filesystem", or press folder up until you get to /

Double click the /etc folder and then scroll down to the "fstab" file and double click it

Find the line that says "UUID=[some number/letter sequence] /dev/mapper/cruptswap1" and then a bunch of other parameters and then put a hashtag (#) in front of it to "comment" it

The drive will no longer attempt to mount at boot though you can mount it manually through the "disks" application that you can access from the dash.